# Get all the children top and left

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, offset, children

I want to get all children offset top inside parent by using jquery and javascript but I only found a few ways to use loop and it's very long so I believe there is something shorter for this

And i never actually learn jquery from A to Z so if it has any solution can you tell me ? Thanks

I want achieve some thing like

```
var top = $("#storage").children().each().offset().top;
```

And it will way more beautiful if it is already sorted to array by jquery something like

```
var top = [122,213,123];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) (and [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert to a regular array).

```js
let top = $("#storage").children().map((_, el) => $(el).offset().top).get();
```